# What exactly is an XPS File & Does It Play Any Role in Computing Today?

Tags: printing

Whenever I print a document whether it be Word, Powerpoint or Excel etc, I always see an option called **Microsoft XPS Document Writer**.

What exactly is an XPS file, is there any reason to actually use this print option and create such a file or is it in fact a redundant format no longer used ?

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia article yet? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification

Comment: @daxlerod No I haven't seen that article (yet ?)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially it is [Microsoft's answer to the PDF](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/print-to-the-microsoft-xps-document-writer).  Once you print to it, you it looks just like it would if you printed it on paper, and you can send that to anyone (just like you would a PDF file) to be viewed at their leisure.

Comment: But is it fair to say that people don't bother with it, and just use PDF instead ?

Comment: Would you say that people don't bother with Linux, because Windows is more popular?  It is fair to say that more people use PDFs, yes.  I couldn't speak as to whether or not people bother with the XPS writer.    Only some programs come with the ability to write to a PDF file, and not everyone knows about the free utilities like CutePDF that enable them to print to a PDF instead of paper.  It's fair to say that a large number of users don't know about writing to either a PDF or an XPS document.

Comment: I don't think comparing using Linux to Windows can be made in the same respect as using or creating XPS files to PDF Files. I will agree with you that there may well be alot of people who don't know about creating PDFs however (or XPS docs)

Comment: Sure it can.  The comparison of Windows to Linux (80% to 10%, or 8 times the number of users) is as good an example as any to show a comparison of popularity.  Both OSes allow you to do most of the same things, just as PDF files and XPS files allow you to most of the same things... and there are compatibility issues with the OSes and the documents.  Seems quite an apt comparison.

Comment: I can see what you are saying. I'll think i'll stick with PDFs though.

Comment: I agree that you should.  Personally, I'm one step beyond that, in that I won't use Microsoft Office products at all.  I don't like their attempts to force users to use THEIR document formats as opposed to a universal one (xps, docx, etc.)

Comment: You don't use PDFs either ?

Comment: PDFs aren't a Microsoft product.  For compatibility sake, when necessary, I will print to a PDF (as opposed to an XPS or other un-editable document format) simply because almost everyone can view it.  However, using a PDF isn't the same as... say... using a .docx format.  If I need to send something compatible with Microsoft Word, I can create a .doc file with LibreOffice, or even Google Docs.

Comment: I know what you are talking about. I misinterpreted what you meant when you said you are "one step beyond that". Thx very much for your help.